ContourPlot3D uniform color regardless of view point
Working with ContourPlot3D I need my 2-surface to have the same color regardless of the viewpoint. However, when I rotate the figure, the darkness of the color changes. These two images belong to the same plane (same color) but different viewpoints


My actual code is pretty complex but here is a MWE to play with:
ContourPlot3D[{x1 + 2 x2 - 2 x3 == 0}, {x1, -1, 1}, {x2, -1, 
  1}, {x3, -1, 1}, Mesh -> None]


Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}

Update (I am not sure why the first version affected the legends color):
ContourPlot3D[{x1 + 2 x2 - 2 x3 == 0, 
  2 x1 + 1 x2 + 3 x3 == 0}, {x1, -1, 1}, {x2, -1, 1}, {x3, -1, 1}, 
 Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> {ColorData[97, 1], ColorData[97, 2]}, 
 Lighting -> {"Ambient", White}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]



ContourPlot3D[{x1 + 2 x2 - 2 x3 == 0, 
  2 x1 + 1 x2 + 3 x3 == 0}, {x1, -1, 1}, {x2, -1, 1}, {x3, -1, 1}, 
 Mesh -> None, 
 ContourStyle -> {Glow[ColorData[97, 1]], Glow[ColorData[97, 2]]}, 
 Lighting -> None]




Thanks! This works great, but it distorts the legends. They do not have the same colors as the corresponding surfaces

I updated my answer.
